# Did the invention of group theory help at all in the way we look at complex analysis?

Tags: group-theory, complex-analysis

Did the invention of group theory help at all in the way we look at complex analysis? Particularly, I am interested in the work of Abel. If so, how?

Comment: You may be interested in the [History of Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/) site.